# Is it possible to avoid exceptions while making a blocking call to NetworkStream.Read()?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, networkstream

My program creates a number of outgoing connections (using `TcpClient`) to a remote host. It creates 3 threads for each connection:

The first thread then fires off 2 child threads: one to read, the other to write. After the writing is done the write thread notifies the first thread and returns, the first thread then closes the `TcpClient` instance (via a `using()` statement). I cannot see how I can unblock the read thread.

It is my expectation that calling `Read()` on a `NetworkStream` that had been closed would return EOS/EOF (`-1`), indicating the end of all data that had been received, so checking for that would be sufficient.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
void DoTask() { // called from UI thread

    Thread taskThread = new Thread( DoTaskInternal );
    taskThread.Start();
}

EventWaitHandle _taskDone = new EventWaitHandle( false );

void DoTaskInternal() {

    using(TcpClient client = ConnectToRemote()) {

        Thread readThread = new Thread( ReadLoop );
        Thread writeThread = new Thread( WriteLoop );

        readThread.Start( client.GetStream() );
        writeThread.Start( client.GetStream() );

        _taskDone.WaitOne();

        // the writeThread will have returned, but wait for the readThread to finish:
        readThread.Join();
    }

}

void ReadLoop(NetworkStream s) {

    StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader( s );

    Int32 nc; Char c;
    while( (nc = rdr.Read()) != -1 ) {
        Char c = (Char)nc;
        // do stuff with each char received
    }
}

void WriteLoop(NetworkStream s) {

    // (write to the stream here)

    // tell the other thread we're done:
    _taskDone.Set();
}
```

However, in my experience, the call to `rdr.Read()` results in one of 3 different exceptions being thrown depending on the exact timing.

> System.IO.IOException("Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall.")

This exception happens about 90% of the time.

> System.InvalidOperationException("The stream does not support reading.")

This one only happened once. It has the exact same stack-trace as the `IOException`. This must happen when the read thread is inside the `NetworkStream.Read` method before it calls `streamSocket.Receive`.

> System.ObjectDisposedException("Cannot access a disposed object.)

This happened about 9% of the time. This is the first check inside `NetworkStream.Read`.

However, surely having one thread reading from a network stream while another thread closes the connection must be a common-scenario, so catching (and swallowing) these exceptions seems hardly ideal.

Is there a better way to deal with this that allows me to read character-by-character from the network stream, but not have to deal with exceptions when the connection is closed?

Comment: No, that's a highly unrealistic goal.  Somebody else's software or machine *will* cause exceptions in your program and there's nothing you can do about it.  However, some of these exceptions do appear of your own making, ODE certainly is.  Happens when you jerk the floor mat by closing the socket.  Starting a thread and completely ignoring exceptions is guaranteed to get your program to fail sooner or later.

Comment: @HansPassant How can I safely close a socket while another thread is blocked and waiting to read from it?

Comment: It is entirely safe to call Socket.Close or Dispose.  You are guaranteed to get an ODE in your worker thread.  Catch it and get out immediately.  Simple and safe, you can only get it wrong by hoping that Read() doesn't throw.